# What is the correct way to use setVisibility() in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a view where a button can be clicked for additional information. The information is initially hidden and it is revealed on click. If I have clicked it and then I scroll down, the layout is reused. Now the new view displays the hidden information without having been clicked as it is reused.

How to avoid or solve this issue?

EDIT: One way is that I hide the view again in the onBindViewHolder. But would like a better method

Comment: provide your adapter code

Comment: You have to set the visibility when you bind data. That's the purpose of the bind method. What kind of better solution do you have in mind?

Comment: Instead of undoing all the previous operations on the view. Can it be told to rebuild?

Comment: @suku I have no idea what you are taking about. What do you mean with undoing all previous operations? Makes no sense. And what do you mean with rebuild? Can what be told to rebuild? Please if you don't understand just post the code of your adapter and I can fix it for you...

Comment: Recyclerview reuses old view, so I was wondering if I can force the recyclerview to reinflate (used the wrong word initially). Anton clarified that that would be taking lot more time then just undoing the view changes in the reused view.

Answer (score 0):

you have to track the position clicked.

```
  //global scope
int pos_clicked=-1;
class View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txt;
    public View_Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setOnclickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        pos_clicked=getAdapterPosition();
          notifyDataSetChanged();
    }}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(View_Holder holder, int position) {
    if(pos_clicked==position){
        holder.txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        holder.txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }}
```

Answer (score -1):

the reason you faced this problem is that RecyclerView tries to recycle views to prevent creating each view when user scrolling,

So you need to save the state of current position object, as you don't push your adapter here I try to explain it in sample adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, final int position) {
    SampleObject eachObject = data.get(position);

    if(eachObject.getCurrentState() == SampleObject.CLICKED){
        // hide button
        // show additional information
    }
    else {
        // show button
        // hide additional information view
    }
```

and in your ContactViewHolder class

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.show_data:
                SampleObject eachObject = data.get(position);
                eachObject.setCurrentState(SampleObject.CLICKED);
                break;
```